# mysql workbench visualization for schema

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have an existing database and have recently downloaded mysql workbench. I was wondering if anyone could walk me through how to navigate the workbench and how to get a visualization of the RDB. I'd like to know how all the tables are related to each other.

Answer (score 27):

Go to `Database Menu` and select `Reverse engineer`, or simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (OS X).

Comment: What's your reason to vote me down?? :|

Comment: Hi @Nima Ghaedsharafi, your answer helped me - so I voted! :)

Comment: I'll add that this also depends on your database design. We have Hybris eCommerce database and when I went to attempt to reverse engineer it, it had over 1000+ objects, and complained until I drastically reduced that number to around 100 which defeats the purpose. 

And, even after filtering it down to a core 100 objects (customers, carts, orders, shipping) the cards were still a mess and didn't create an interesting map that I could easily explore.